# mplayer/VLC video playlist with pauses

Tags: video, vlc, playlist, mplayer

Before I start re-encoding a bunch of video files into a single one... Is there a way to create a playlist, in any format supported by either Mplayer or VLC (or both), which instructs the player to pause for N seconds before moving on to the next video file?

Ideally:

- no extra video artefacts, such as black video sequences, should be used;
- player-specific tricks are OK, but no programming please;
- OS-specific scripting should be avoided;
- playing the whole list should be gap-less: during a pause the player should stream black frames.

For those needing a reason before doing anything: this is to spare the lazy operator the tedious task of watching a screening of many short films ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of your files into a common folder, fire up the terminal, `cd` to it,  and execute:

```
for v in *; do mpv "$v"; clear; sleep 5; done
```

Notes:

- Make sure the folder contains only videos. Otherwise it *will* try to play sounds, and other files.
- You can replace [`mpv`](http://mpv.io) with `mplayer`, `vlc` or whichever player you prefer.
- `clear` is optional: it just clears out the verbosity that could scare your audience.

Comment: That'd be way too easy ;-) Actually, it's not OS independent, and doesn't play gap-less: the public would see a fastidious context switch between film streaming and window manager/shell background. As for gap-less playback, though still with no pause, I discovered that VLC does a good job, whereas Mplayer needs some workaround based on FIFOs as [proposed here for audio playing](http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1347&sid=6bcc01779849cc25db475725b0f05350)

Comment: Right. What if you added a black video between your videos in your playlist to simulate pauses?

Comment: That was indeed my first idea of a workaround! It looks like there's no other (easy) way of sorting this out, so I'll post another Q/A about generating black video content, then will come back here.

Comment: @sphakka Let me know where you posted it, and I'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

did you manage to solve your issue solely within `mplayer`?  I have a similar question, but not video, just audio, and I did not find the option for adding pause after playback, so resorted to:

- create an empty 3s audio file,
- insert it in the playback list between every real file,
- mplayer the list.

in practice:

```
sox -n -r 44100 -c 2 silence.wav trim 0.0 3.0
mplayer $(for i in 02[1-9]*.mp3; do echo $i silence.wav; done)
```

I am aware this is os-dependent.  I prefer this to the `for` loop because this way I only have a single `mplayer` invocation, so I can set volume, and move back and forth among chapters.